# Configuring gmail, postfix with my domain?

Tags: email, configuration, dns, gmail, postfix-mta

I have a gmail account with my domain (contact@mybus.com) also I have my website at DigitalOcean with postfix working fine.

My domain "www.mybus.com" has his dns point to my website at DigitalOcean and I wanted to use my gmail account to receive and send e-mails instead of postfix, how can I configure to do this?

Another question, is possible to receive e-mail at gmail accounts and send trought postfix at DigitalOcean?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I login in my google's account with my domain and I get google's test domain, like:
contact@mybus.com.test-google-a.com

and I forward all my received email to the domain above, this configuration was made in postfix at DigitalOcean.

Now I'm receiving and delivering e-mails at DigitalOcean with postfix and using gmail services to consult my e-mails.

=)

Answer (score 1):

Add below to main.cf in postfix

```
install 
yum -y install cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-plain

myhostname=<hostname>
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt

/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
add gmail account details to above file
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 xxxxx@gmail.com:passwd

use postmap to create db
postmap sasl_passwd
```

Restart postfix then
this should work.